# How can I debug CDK python app and have the context variables available?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Is there a way to debug CDK python app (in IntelliJ) and have the variables from cdk.json loaded?
If I simply run "app.py" the context variables are missing so the app does not run correctly.
Is there some configuration which I can do?

Comment: did you find solution maybe to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Python Debug Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2022.3/run-debug-configuration-python-remote-debug.html) option. First create a config, which will listen to e.g. `localhost:10888`.

Run the debug server, it will then report "Waiting for process connection…".

Then change your `cdk.json -> app` value to `"python3 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 10888 --file app.py"`. Your PyCharm may be located elsewhere – I got this string by debugging another file in my PyCharm project.

If you now run `cdk synth`, it should connect to the debug server you've started.

An option to modifying your `cdk.json` is to add the `settrace` command to the program (the `app.py` or somewhere before your breakpoint) :

```
import pydevd_pycharm
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('localhost', port=10888, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

This will require `pydevd-pycharm` to be pip installed (the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog for "Python Debug Server" should inform which version is required).